# Set of points equidistant from circle and a point in its interior.

Tags: geometry

The distance from a point to a circle is defined here, for an interior point as the follows:

Given an interior point, we draw a line  that passes through the circle center and this point. The intersection with the circle is marked. The distance from the point and the intersection is the desired distance. Likewise for an exterior point.

So, the exercise asks me to find the set of points equidistant from an interior point and the circle. Which set will this be? I know that the set of equidistant points from a point is a circle, but the set of equidistant points from the circle is kind of hard. How can I think of it for the exterior and interior point cases?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the problem. You have a point $P$ and a circumference $C$. A point $X$ is equidistant from these if $d(X, P) = d(X, C)$, regardless of what that value is. The problem, I believe, asks you to describe the set $\{ X \mid d(X, P) = d(X, C) \}$. In the case where $P$ is actually the center of the circle $C$, the answer is "a circle whose radius is half that of $C$." For a point not at the center of $C$, I suspect that the answer might also be "a circle of some radius", or maybe "an ellipse", but I'm not certain of either of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be any point in the interior of a circle centered at $O$ with radius $R$.

For any point $X$ on the plane, independent of whether it is inside, on or outside the circle, its distance to the circumference is equal to $|R - |OX||$. 
The condition that $X$ is equidistance to $P$ and the circumference is simply

$$|XP| = |R - |OX||$$

It is easy to see no $X$ on or outside the circle can satisfy the condition.
This means $X$ is an interior point and the condition reduces to

$$|XP| = R - |OX| \quad \iff \quad |XP| + |OX| = R$$

This means the locus of $X$ is an ellipse with $O$ and $P$ as foci and semi-major axis $\frac12 R$.